# use 'if' in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I have a search field in my application, and I'm using SQL.

My application has 3 separate `ComboBox`es that allow the user to choose what he/she wants to search.

For example, we have `Name` , `family name` and `age` in the search field, and I want to choose the people with `age 20` or people with `age 20 and named "john" or other states`.

So should I use a general procedure of `IF`, `ELSE`, `WHERE` to support all of these states?

Comment: Do you know about [SQL Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx)?

Comment: You said it yourself, just change the syntax of your English a bit: "age = 20 or (age = 20 and name = 'John')". Logically this is the same as "age = 20 or name = 'John'.

Comment: select * from yourTable where Name=@Name and Family=@Family and Age=@Age, and pass the values from your ComboBoxes. What have you tried?

Comment: Read between the lines of what he wants to do.  In my opinion he wants to search, but only if the combobox is filled in.  And if it is, then filter.  I may have it wrong, but if not it should be as simple as: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15429110/1795053

Comment: tnx Eli it was usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming variables `@Age`, `@Name`, and `@FamilyName`

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
    (@Age IS NULL OR Age == @Age)
    AND (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')
    AND (@FamilyName IS NULL OR FamilyName LIKE '%' + @FamilyName+ '%')
```

No need to do an if.  But if you wanted to do an IF inside sql it's `CASE WHEN <true state> THEN <true action> ELSE <false action> END`

Comment: This wont work. What happens if the user doesnt want to filter by any one of the three options?

Comment: now I see no need to do an IF TnX

Comment: @CathalMF then all three will be ignored.  All three variables will be NULL, which will satisfy the first half of all three OR statements, thus filtering by nothing.

Comment: so what should I do when the user ask for all, for ex in the age combo box the user choose "all" to see all of the people in every age??? I mean in this case i should search just about name and family name and age is not important. Am I Right?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for If-Else in sql is

```
IF yourconditon
BEGIN
  //sql query
END
ELSE
  BEGIN
     //sqlquery
   End
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you execute your sql in database?
Is it an stored procedure in database, or do you just send sql statements to database.

If it is the second, just do the if-then-else stuff in your c# code and send different sql-statements to your database.

Comment: yes it is an stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options, and would suggest performance testing both (as always).

1. Dynamic SQL.

Build the SQL dynamically based on the parameters used, so;

```
declare sqlTxt VARCHAR(max)
delcare params VARCHAR(128)

params = 'Age INT, Name VARCHAR(128), FamilyName VARCHAR(128)'
sqlText = 'SELECT field Name From Table WHERE 1=1'

IF (IS NOT NULL) sqlText += 'AND Age == @Age '
IF (IS NOT NULL) sqlText += 'AND Name LIKE %@Name%'
IF (IS NOT NULL) sqlText += 'AND FamilyName LIKE %FamilyName%'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlText, @params, @Age = @Age, @Name = @Name, @FamilyName = @FamilyName
```

1. Handle in SQL

Use the solution posted by Eli Gassert.

Generally, with smaller queries you should be fine to use option 2, but if you expand your search to include lots of different parameters be aware of 'parameter sniffing' which could slow you down.

Basically test both ways if performance is an issue.

Comment: it is unclear where the literals here start and end; this matters because you *might* be creating a SQL injection hole, or you *might* be including the parameter names in the literals and using sq_executesql (which would be fine)

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is create the SQL in your windows project based on what the user has chosen.

```
StringBuilder mySQL = new StringBuilder();

if(Name != "")
  mySQL.Append("Name like '%" + Name + "'%");

if(mySQL != "" && (familyName != "" || age != ""))
  mySQL.Append(" AND");

if(familyName != "")
  mySQL.Append(" familyName like '%" + familyName + "%');
```

And continue on with the rest of your conditions. 
Append the stringbuilder string to your SELECT query.

```
string finalSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE " + mySQL.toString();
```

Comment: Nice SQL injection hole there

Comment: Well he will still need to validate what the user enters to prevent this but that wasnt in the question!!

Comment: no, you don't fix injection by validating input; you fix injection by using parameters - which is clearly ***not*** what is being shown here. The code shown above is ***actively dangerous*** and should be strongly discouraged. If you have code that "validate[s] what the user enters" and then uses concatenation, then your code is fundamentally broken.

Comment: Ok i understand your point about it being a vunerabily but what do you mean by its "fundamentally broken"?

Comment: a combination of "really really dangerous", "unable to use properly typed data" (impacts indexing and parsing), "unable to re-use query plans", and all of these things are *completely unnecessary and trivially avoidable*; that sounds pretty broken to me.